# UITextView text not vertically aligned

Tags: ios, uitextview

When adding text to an `UITextView` the text is not centred vertically. But as soon as I select the `UITextView` the text goes up correcting the initial position.

[image: UITextView initial state]

[image: UITextView after selecting it]

The yellow represents the `UITextView` frame. The green is the `BackgroundColorAttribute` of the text. As you can see from the pictures the text goes up when editing.

The reason why the text goes up is because the `scrollEnabled` is set to YES. Setting it to NO will just maintain the incorrect position.

I'm using a custom font but this happens with the system font as well.

What can I do to correct the initial position of the text?

Thanks.

Comment: it seems you have to increase the UITextview height. just try it once.

Comment: Adjusting UITextView height is a workaround. As you can see the height is correct because when I select the UITextView the text fixes it's position and it's not cut off. This fixed position should be the initial position.

Comment: I remember in my app, Textview having some padding in four sides. Thats what once focus is out it's taking the actual position of the text attribute. In textField we can observe the text attribute padding.

Answer (score 0):

If

> textview.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

or

> [textView sizeToFit];

will not help you, you probably should edit text frame and/or rect.

Comment: I'm already using NSTextAlignmentCenter. sizeToFit decreases my font size which is already the max font size. The frame size is fine because when I start editing the text I don't change it and the text shifts to the correct position.

Comment: frame also has positions, besides size.

Comment: I meant frame. Not just size. Sorry

Answer (score -1):

Use this line to vertically center the text

```
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

Comment: It's a textView. Not a textField.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a similar solution to this [here](http://imagineric.ericd.net/2011/03/10/ios-vertical-aligning-text-in-a-uitextview/)?